# What is the type/class of a dynamically imported module in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have problem finding the type of an imported module in typescript, could someone help me?
To clarify my question I have a module `module.ts`

```
export class RSL1 {};
```

Then I load it in my `index.ts` with

```
const script =  await import('module.js');
```

It loads correctly and in a browser in debug console it is printed out as `Module {Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}`

But what is the typescript type of the `script` variable? The `Module` class is not known to the compiler.
I need just the generic abstract type of the module, not the "runtime" instance. I guess the members of the module depend on what is actually exported in the module. But I don't need that.

Answer (score 1):

For now it's 'object', as stated in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32646):

> We currently don't have a way to represent values with properties that aren't inherited from Object. A solution for this would ideally also be usable to fix Object.create(null)

This affects all [exotic objects](/q/31709156) that deviate from default prototype inheritance.